# Converir objeto generico a especifico

Tags: java

¿Cómo podría en java convertir una lista de objetos a objetos del tipo "NombreClase" teniendo "NombreClase" en un String.?

Tengo N tablas desde la fuente A que llega en Json, necesito comparar con o que tengo en SQL server

Los pojos ya existen entonces necesito trasformar lo que me llega en json al pojo de la tala SQL

Answer (score 3):

¡Hola!

Una posible opción para esto es utilizar Reflection API, aunque realmente terminarías teniendo un Object, si lo asignas a una variable. Te dejo un ejemplo.

```
Object something = "something";
String theType = "java.lang.String";
Class<?> theClass = Class.forName(theType);
Object obj = theClass.cast(something);
```

No obstante, el tipado dinámico no es algo que tenga mucho sentido en Java, por como funciona el lenguaje, por lo que si editas la pregunta, y das algo de contexto sobre por qué necesitarías eso, quizás se te pueda dar una solución más adecuada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahí edité y describí lo que necesito hacer.